# Which event of repeater control fires at the time of page_init or page_load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, asprepeater

I have a scenario like facebook wall where I need to display image of user in repeater control who posted.

I have tried `myrepeater_ItemCommand1` or `myrepeater_ItemDataBound` but not working.

Code behind

```
protected void myrepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        LinkButton lblPostedBy = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lblPostedBy");
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "select image from " + lblPostedBy.Text + " where id=1";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        string imageurl = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();
        Image Image1 = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("Image1");
        Image1.ImageUrl = imageurl;
    }

    catch (Exception a)
    {
        lblMsg.Text = a.Message;
        msgbox.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

and same in `myrepeater_ItemCommand1` which is working if I click button inside Repeater.

I wanted to know that which event of `Repeater control` fires at the time of `Page_Load` or `Page_Init`.

Or, kindly suggest me other way to accomplish my task.

BTW, my project is in `C# ASP.NET 4`.

Comment: why myrepeater_ItemDataBound does not work for you? That's where you should be handling this. Post the code for ItemDataBound, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the post has been saved, you should rebind the repeater. After rebinding the repeater, your updates should display.

```
//update some stuff in the database

Repeater1.DataSource = RepeaterDataSource();
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

**EDIT**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" ...>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="imgProfilePic" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ProfileImageUrl")%>' ... />
        <%#Eval("PostMessage")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And in the code behind:

```
protected void BindDataToRepeater()
{
    Repeater1.DataSource = GetUserPosts();
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

After an update:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //save post to database
    SavePost();

    //rebind the repeater to display the post that was just added
    BindDataToRepeater();
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling the database in the `ItemDataBound` event? Can't you just return that information in the select that gets all of the posts?

Comment: Because, many users will post their feed and using FindControl I can find that which user has sent which data. According to that, I select Username of user (lblPostedBy) and search for image url in the column 'Image' of his table. Is there any other way to use FindControl for finding lblPostedBy apart from this I have used?

Comment: But you can return the image URL in the select that gets all of the posts, and use databinding syntax to set the `ImageUrl`. You're just putting an unecessary burden on your database by calling the database for every item that is bound to the repeater.

Comment: Sir, Will you please give me suitable code example for that? I cant understand.